# C# -- should we check the pass-in parameter in the lambda?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Should we check pass-in parameters of the lambda expression?
In other words, should we check the parameter o and s?

```
class MainWindow : Form /// implementation I
{
    ...
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuFileExit = new ToolStripMenuItem();

    private void BuildMenus()
    {
        ...
        mnuFileExit.Click += (o, s) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} sent this event", o.ToString()));
            Application.Exit();
        };
        ... 
    }
    ...
}

class MainWindow : Form /// implementation II
{
    ...
    private ToolStripMenuItem mnuFileExit = new ToolStripMenuItem();

    private void BuildMenus()
    {
        ...
        mnuFileExit.Click += (o, s) =>
        {
            if (o != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} sent this event", o.ToString()));
                Application.Exit();
            }
        };
        ... 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: just a short question, is the delegate really necessary? it might turn into a code smell in the long run. my 2 cents.

Comment: the delegate can access your local variables in your BuildMenus method. In some cases, it would be very convenient.

Answer (score 4):

No need to check that the 1st parameter is null; because it is the sender and is always non-null.

I disagree with the choice of argument names (`o` and `s`).  Normally the first parameter is named `s` (for sender) and the second parameter is named `e` (for event).

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to add null check to the sender (o) as it is the event sender. It is mnuFileExit which wouldn't be null.